# Problemas com banco de dados

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, amazon-aws, modelo-relacional

Bom galera criei um conta na aws, para gerencia-la com mysql anotei a senha o usuariomaster e tenho certeza que essa desgraça não loga, já mechi no ec2, coloquei pra ser acessado por qualquer ip com aurora e my sql só que não loga, peço a ajuda de você por que tenho um tempo limitado pra construir esse banco de dados.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Eu arrumei a solução galera, você modifica o banco de dados e coloca public acess, funcionou, não sei se é a melhor forma , mas funcionou.